# When to set Id and when to set Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public class Book {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public int? AddedByUserId { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; } = new HashSet<Author>();
}


public class Author {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int BookId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public int? AddedByUserId { get; set; }

  public Book Book { get; set; } = new Book();
}
```

I try to add an `Author` and set the `BookId` to an existing value.

```
var newAuthor = new Author();
newAuthor.BookId = 1;

_dbContext.Authors.Add(author);
```

When I inspect the `ChangeTracker` to see what DbContext is going to do:

```
var longView = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView;
```

It indicates that `Author`, `Book`, and `User` will all be added.

```
Author {Id: -2147482646} **Added**
  Id: -2147482646 PK Temporary
  AddedByUserId: 1
  DateAdded: '11/25/2022 8:22:11 PM'
  Name: 'My Author Name'
  BookId: -2147482643 FK Temporary
  Book: {Id: -2147482643}
Book {Id: -2147482643} **Added**
  Id: -2147482643 PK Temporary
  AddedByUserId: -2147482645 FK Temporary
  DateAdded: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'
  Name: ''
  AddedByUserId: {Id: -2147482645}
User {Id: -2147482645} **Added**
  Id: -2147482645 PK Temporary
  DateAdded: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'
  Name: <null>
  RowVersion: <null>
```

How can I do it so that only the new `Author` gets added when the `BookId` foreign key is set? Should I be setting objects instead of Ids?

```
newAuthor.Book = _dbContext.Book.Find(1);
```

Comment: You might want to change your relationship of `Book` and `Author` to be N:M, since authors can write multiple books and books can be written by multiple authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newAuthor.Book` is not null and is not tracked by EF so it will consider it as a new book. There are multiple options:

1. "Clear" the book object:

```cs
var newAuthor = new Author();
newAuthor.BookId = 1;
newAuthor.Book = null;
```

2. Attach the book:

```cs
var newAuthor = new Author();
newAuthor.Book.Id = 1;
_dbContext.Books.Attach(newAuthor.Book);

_dbContext.Authors.Add(author);
```

3. Fetch the book from database (as you have suggested yourself)

Comment: You are correct, I am initializing the `Book` in the `Author` class. I will go with a modified version of 1, which will simply be to allow the `Book` to be nullable and not initialize it in `Author`. Option 3 is a very good approach, but I really don't want to do a db lookup when I already know the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't modify the foreign keys directly, instead let ef core do its job by setting the object itself. Also don't `new()` reference navigation properties:

```
public Book Book { get; set; } = new Book();
```

doing it for collection navigation properties is good because it avoids null exceptions when trying to add to the collection, for example.